# A math modelling interview question

Tags: modeling

What's the best way to (relative) grade a class (of 50 students) on a test (with 7 questions)?

They did not want the traditional percentile-intervals answer, but a more CS-ey one.

It's a pretty open ended question, they asked to assume the following framework:

Input

1. [m_1,...,m_50], where each m_i is a 7-vector for marks scored in the 7 questions for each of the 50 students.

   [c_1,...,c_7], where each c_i is a vector of 'concepts' tested by each question. c_i's need not be disjoint. We can assume to have an importance ordering amongst elements of union(c_i).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplistic approach: Assuming that all concepts have the same value I would just sum it all up. One point for each concept everywhere.

Holistic approach: It could be that the question with more concepts is significantly harder than the question with fewer (and worth more than the sum of concepts). Concepts "interact" with each other. To alleviate this I would put a value of (N over C) to each question, where N is the size of the vector of concepts, and C is total number of concepts. And then I would sum it all up.

True holistic approach: If concepts are repeated in different questions then we should "tone down" their influence. However I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Maybe we should divide each (N over C) value with the number of repetitions of each concept involved.

I ignored the importance ordering of concepts, because I don't know how to put a value on that.